# Generating a basis of the orthocomplement of a vector in $\mathbb{E}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

There is a vector $v\in\mathbb{E}^{4}$. I can define an orthogonal complement with basis vectors $e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}$ by the rule:

$$e_{i}=P_{i}\cdot v,$$

where

$$P_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
 , P_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
 , P_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} .$$

If components of $v$ are continuous function on a curve, then components of $e_{i}$ will be the continuous functions too. Thus this rule allows me to define a local chart in some neighborhood of the curve. 
I know that the same trick works in $\mathbb{E}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}^{8}$ sapces.

**Question:** Is there a general way to uniquely define a basis for orthogonal complement of the given vector in any dimansional euclidean space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and in fact the examples $\Bbb E^2, \Bbb E^4, \Bbb E^8$ mentioned in the question are the only (nontrivial) Euclidean spaces in which one *can* do this. (Of course, one can do this for $\Bbb E^1$, for which the orthocomplement of a nonzero vector is trivial.)

More precisely:

Suppose one has matrices $Q_1, \ldots, Q_{n - 1} \in M(n, \Bbb E)$ such that for any vector $v \in \Bbb E^n$ the ordered set $(P_a \cdot v)$ is a basis of $\langle v\rangle^{\perp}$. On the other hand, for all $v$ in the $(n - 1)$-sphere $\Bbb S^{n - 1} \subset \Bbb E^n$, we may identify the tangent space $T_v \Bbb S^{n - 1}$ to $\Bbb S^{n - 1}$ at $v$ with $\langle v \rangle^{\perp}$, and so the vector fields $v \mapsto Q_a \cdot v$, $a = 1, \ldots, n - 1$, comprise a global frame on $\Bbb S^{n - 1}$, that is, $\Bbb S^{n - 1}$ is *parallelizable*. It was proven (both by Kervaire and Bott-Milnor, IIRC) that the only parallelizable spheres are $\Bbb S^0, \Bbb S^1, \Bbb S^3, \Bbb S^7$, so we must have $n = 1, 2, 4, 8$.

One can construct the sets $(Q_a)$ uniformly the four cases: For each $n$, consider the unique real division algebra ($\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb H$, or $\Bbb O$) of dimension $n$ and pick a (real) orthogonal basis $(1, f_1, \ldots f_{n - 1})$ of it. By construction, $(f_a v)$ is a basis of $\langle v \rangle^{\perp}$, so we can take $Q_a$ to be the matrix representation w.r.t. the above basis of the left multiplication map $x \mapsto f_a x$. For example, taking the usual basis $(1, i, j, k)$ of $\Bbb H$, we get the matrices
$$
   Q_1 = -P_3, \quad Q_2 = P_1, \quad Q_3 = P_2 ,
$$
where the matrices $P_a$ are as in the question.

Here are some [notes](http://math.mit.edu/~mdono/haynes-notes.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: Cool, I've got it! Thank you.
I understood that it is impossible to construct orthogonal continues linearly independent vector fields in $\mathbb{E}^3$ in general case. 
But what changes if $v$ is not **any** vector field, but it is a tangent vector of a given smooth curve on $\mathbb{E}^n$ not having self-intersections?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was helpful. As for your second question, can you be more precise about what kind of object it is for which you want to guarantee existence?

Comment: There is a smooth curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$. It has a tangent vector $v$ at each points. Is it possible to define $n−1$ smooth vector fields $e_{1},...,e_{n-1}$ s.t. at each point of $\gamma$ the ordered set $v,e_1,...e_{n-1}$ be a basis? I mean is there a common approach to generate such vector fields?

Comment: Provided that $\gamma$ is generic at the parameter value $t_0$ in the sense that $(\gamma'(t_0), \ldots, \gamma^{(n)}(t_0))$ is linearly independent at $\gamma(t_0)$, applying the Gram-Schmidt Process to that basis yields a canonical orthonormal frame $(E_0, \ldots, E_{n - 1})$; in particular, $E_0$ is the unit tangent vector, $E_1$ is the unit vector in the direction of the normal acceleration, and so on. By construction, if the curve is smooth, so are the frame components, $E_a(t)$.

Comment: As far as I understand, if $\gamma$ is a straight line this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's correct (except in the trivial case $n = 1$); in that case, $\gamma'' = 0$, so the $n$-tuple I mentioned is not linearly independent. Of course, for a straight line, one can simply pick a suitable constant frame.